# Проблема кодировки

Tags: кодировка, javascript

Есть js скрипт с ленты.ру:

http://lenta.ru/export/js.htm

Вставляется он скриптом загрузки, но так как я использую англоязычный движок - сбивается кодировка. А именно - идут знаки вопроса. Можно ли его как принудительно приводить к utf-8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У него заголовок идёт: `Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251`

В любом случае браузер будет принимать его за html документ.

Как вариант можно в теге указать

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="..." **charset="windows-1251"**></script>
```

Comment: Напиши здесь, если попробуешь. Мне самому интересно.

Comment: Работает, раньше не мог написать потому как вопрос бажил.